# How to compare two different CSV files with different number of columns and rows by keyword?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Without using the diff option.

I have two different CSV files (I know what is the names of the columns headlines)- old.csv and new.csv. they are with a different number of rows and columns. the CSV files can include numbers, strings, chars, and special characters.
For example:

old.csv

```
     round    date  first  second  third  fourth  fifth  sixth
1     2  2021.04      2    45e69     10    16      4565   37
2     3  2021.04      4      15    456as  df924     35   4N320
4     5  2021.03      4    43!d9    23      26      29     33
```

new.csv

```
     round    date  first  second  third  fourth  fifth  sixth
0     1  2021.04      1      14     15      24      40     41
1     2  2021.04      2    45e69    10      16     4565    37
2     3  2021.04      4      15    456as   df924    35    4N320
3     4  2021.03     10      11     20      21     24325   41
5     6  2021.03    4321       9   2#@6     28     34350   41
```

Line 1 and 2 from both CSV are the same.

Now, I want to print out the difference between new.csv compared to old.csv.
I want to print out only the new lines in new.csv file.
like that:

result.csv

```
     round    date  first  second  third  fourth  fifth  sixth
0     1  2021.04      1     14     15      24     40     41
3     4  2021.03     10     11     20      21     24325  41
5     6  2021.03    4321    9     2#@6     28     34350  41
```

Counting the lines was for easier reading.
I want the headline columns will be kept in the result.csv file.

The option I think that might help here is using keywords.
For example, comparing the two CSV files by columns "first" and "fifth"- if one of the columns is not the same, print that in the result.csv file.

Comment: Is there anything you have tried so far? Please post your own efforts to solve the task so far. ([How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: @Felix, I have added few code examples

Comment: What is not working with option one? (Except that it is not finding lines that are in file one but not in file one.)

Comment: Yes, I'm having a tough time with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seperately need to check each column you want to compare. The following code is one option how to do this.

```
import pandas as pd

def getLinesOnlyInA(dfa, dfb, result):
    # iterate over all lines in file a
    for index1, row1 in dfa.iterrows():
        aLineIsEqual = False
        # iterate over all lines in file b
        for index2, row2 in dfb.iterrows():
            thisLineIsDifferent = False
            # for each column, check if they are different
            for column in columns:
                if row1[column] != row2[column]:
                    thisLineIsDifferent = True
                    # ionly continue when the fields are the same
                    break
            if not thisLineIsDifferent:
                aLineIsEqual = True
                # only continue when no equal line was found
                break
        # when no equal line was found, add that line to the result
        if not aLineIsEqual:
            result.append(row1)
            
            
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
columns = ['round', 'first', 'fifth']     # columns to be compared
results = []

getLinesOnlyInA(df1, df2, results)        # find all lines only existing in file 1
getLinesOnlyInA(df2, df1, results)        # find all lines only existing in file 2
dfResult = pd.DataFrame(results)          # cast all lines into a dataframe

print(dfResult.to_string())   
dfResult.to_csv('result.csv', sep=',')
```

Result:

```
   round     date  first second third fourth  fifth sixth
2      5  2021.03      4  43!d9    23     26     29    33
0      1  2021.04      1     14    15     24     40    41
3      4  2021.03     10     11    20     21  24325    41
4      6  2021.03   4321      9  2#@6     28  34350    41
```

---

In case one file contains less columns (eg. `file1` does not contain the `date` column), this still works and results in:

```
   round  first second third fourth  fifth sixth     date
2      5      4  43!d9    23     26     29    33      NaN
0      1      1     14    15     24     40    41  2021.04
3      4     10     11    20     21  24325    41  2021.03
4      6   4321      9  2#@6     28  34350    41  2021.03
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a library you can find useful: [csv-diff](https://pypi.org/project/csv-diff/)

You can use it from command line:

```
csv-diff one.csv two.csv --key=id --json
```

or as a python import

```
from csv_diff import load_csv, compare
diff = compare(
    load_csv(open("one.csv"), key="id"),
    load_csv(open("two.csv"), key="id")
)
```

Comment: Hi @svfat, thanks for your answer, but I do not want to use the diff option.

Answer (score 0):

Use **sets** instead of lists after reading two files:

```
fileone = set(fileone)
filetwo = set(filetwo)
```

then in **result** you can get a symmetric difference - all elements of both sets except elements that are in both **fileone** and **filetwo** sets.

```
result = fileone.symmetric_difference(filetwo)
```

Attention: header row is not included in **result** because it is the same in both sets

**Update**: filetwo minus fileone:

```
result = filetwo.difference(fileone)
```

Comment: Hi, it is working well, but I have fixed my question, I want it to print filetwo-(minus)fileone- get only the new results from filetwo after reduce the same results from fileone.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "filetwo-(minus)fileone". Its getting pretty confusing here. Do you want to yield every line that exists in file two but not in file one? (Which is what "filetwo-(minus)fileone" suggests.) Or do you want to yield every line that exists in either of the files but not in the other? (Which is what you actual question post suggests.) Or do you want to yield something completely differen?

Comment: Hi @Felix, I have edited the question to be more clear.